# How do I format the Key in my boto3 lambda function to update dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I need help with figuring out how to format my Key in lambda to update an item in DynamoDB. Below is the code I have but I can't figure out how to format the Key.

My table looks as follows:

[image]

'''

import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
response = client.update_item(
    TableName='hitcounter',
    Key={????????},
    UpdateExpression='ADD visits :incr',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':incr': 1}

)


print(response)
```

'''

ERROR MESSAGE:

'''
{
  "errorMessage": "'path'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 11, in lambda_handler\n    Key={'path': event['path']},\n"
  ]
}

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS docs provides an example for [Updating an item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html):

```
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'username': 'janedoe',
        'last_name': 'Doe'
    },
    UpdateExpression='SET age = :val1',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':val1': 26
    }
)
```

I'm not sure from your question, if the AWS examples are unclear or what is the issue specifically?

Comment: I keep getting this error. I'm assuming that it has to do with my Key. I've tried following documentation but still get it.

'''
 {
  "errorMessage": "'path'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 11, in lambda_handler\n    Key={'path': event['path']},\n"
  ]
}
'''

Comment: @nktanu This is your lambda code issue, not specific to DdB. Can you update the message with the error message, the structure of `event` object and how do you access it?

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to this and learning as much as I can right now. I added the error to to my post. I'm not sure what you mean by the structure of the event and how it's accessed? @Marcin

Comment: can you add log output for the "event" variable? Check on your cloudwatch what the log result and paste here? I guess the problem came there. It's something like event['path'] is missing value.

Comment: @nktanu You have to show what you are actually using in the code. Your code with ` Key={????????},` does not generate such error message.

Comment: Thanks for guidance guys. Here is my cloudwatch log 

[ERROR] KeyError: 'path'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 11, in lambda_handler
    Key={'path': event['path']},

Comment: Key={'path': event['path']},

This is my current code for the Key that delivers the error above

Comment: Got it figured out! It had to do with the defining variables at the top of my code